# Is it possible to fully customize zendesk new web widget (CSS and HTML both)?

Tags: zendesk

Is it possible to fully customize zendesk new web widget (CSS and HTML both)? I have tried searching the web, but I am not able to find any answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to this support post, it appears that the answer to your question is "no":
https://support.zendesk.com/hc/communities/public/posts/204143646-Web-Widget-Customization-Options?locale=en-us

You could probably override the css and/or html using jQuery, but ZD warns against this in the post above, saying that this is not supported.

You may want to post comments in that support post to show your interest in ZD developing this feature.

Comment: You can override the css and html by accessing the appropriate widget elements, but as Jo mentioned, Zendesk will not troubleshoot or fix your code if your widget breaks, nor will they provide suggestions for how to do so.

Answer (score 14):

While you can't customize the button, you can hide it and use your own.  To hide the button, add the following immediately after the widget code:

```
zE(function() {
  zE.hide();
});
```

Then, create your own button that shows the Zendesk form:

```
<button onClick="zE.activate({hideOnClose: true});">Help Me!</button>
```

You can style that however you want.

Source: https://developer.zendesk.com/embeddables/docs/widget/api#ze.sethelpcentersuggestions

Answer (score 0):

Is this this the article you looking for? https://support.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/203908456-Using-Web-Widget-to-embed-customer-service-in-your-website

Comment: kind of but, the coder said they haven't built and CSS and HTML

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. You need to hide widget in script tag for embedding. Than override it's CSS by adding some CSS with overrided classes for widget by js. Right after that activate widget again. This is a dirty way. Be ready for zendesk update widget and your widget would be broken. The best way to get custom widget is using zendesk api

Answer (score 0):

Why not look at the Zendesk API to get your data from Zendesk for the Widget perhaps this will get around the problem your having ?

Answer (score 0):

I am having the issue, not to be able to retrieve the onlie status of chat agents without a premium lisence for the chat. So I do not know how to write a nice button myself.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can customize the widget extensively using the Web SDK for Chat: https://api.zopim.com/web-sdk/

And here's a good demo to build from:
https://github.com/zopim/chat-web-sdk-sample-app

Lastly, an article announcing the functionality:
https://www.zendesk.com/blog/customize-chat-widget-web-sdk/